# Python - How to interupt the main script on Ctrl+C

Tags: python

I am analysing files and it can take a lot of time.
But when I press Ctrl+C to abort the script, Python only stop reading one file and goes to the next. It does not kill the whole scirpt.
How can I do this?

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

folder = '...'
for folder in folders:

    filesInFolder = [f for f in listdir(folder) if isfile(join(folder, f))]

    for file in filesInFolder:

        try:
            with open(folder+'\\'+file, "r") as file:
                # Analyzing

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            # Kill the whole script!
```

For now, my only solution is to kill kill Python and lose all the work done so far...

Comment: "For now, my only solution is to kill Python and lose all the work done so far"... so do you want to kill the script or do you **not** want to kill the script?

Comment: Close your files before you kill the script?

Comment: Just how do you run the script? Do you run `python scriptname.py` or enter the Python shell and run the script or something else? That matters in your question.

Comment: I run it from Spyder using "F5". I want to be able to have a look at the variables content in order to debug and if simply kill Python core, all the workspace is cleared

Answer (score 4):

move try except out of for loop:

```
try:
    for ....
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Comment: I tryed but it does not work. It still just kills the iterration on going, but not the whole script

Answer (score 0):

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import signal

def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    print("Program exited with CTRL+C.")
    #Add whatever you want the program to do on ctrl+c here
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

folder = '...'
for folder in folders:
    filesInFolder = [f for f in listdir(folder) if isfile(join(folder, f))]
    for file in filesInFolder:
        with open(folder+'\\'+file, "r") as file:
            # Analyzing
```

What you want is a signal handler that gets called and terminates the entire script whenever ctrl+c is pressed.  Try placing this code above your current code (with import statement where you have the other imports) and give it a go.  If you want ctrl+c to do other things, such as file closing, place it into the `signal_handler` function.  So perhaps above the `print`  you can add `File.close()` if you've got a file open, etc.

Comment: too complicated. using try except KeyboardInterrupt is the same result without a callback function

Comment: @Daniele I don't think it's too complicated, and it's important to learn proper signal handling.  Your way works too, but it requires `try except` wrapping around the code you're running it for.  The method I've provided works without `try except` blocks, meaning it has greater flexibility for the code.

Comment: I tryed but it does not work. It still just kills the iterration on going, but not the whole script

Comment: @Maxime you're not putting it in the `for` loop are you?  I'll update my answer to show exactly how it should look with your code.